# Stucking with MYSQL to get value from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, json, join

this is my first time asking for help. I am not sure if I'm doing it correctly but here's my problem:

Table structure:

```
Table 'users'             Table 'made'
+--+---------+---------+   +--+---------+---------------+
|id|user_id  |friends  |   |id|p_id     |result         |
+--+---------+---------+   +--+---------+---------------+
|1 |x        |["y","z"]|   |1 | y       |some_text_here |
+--+---------+---------+   +--+---------+---------------+
```

What I got so far:

```
SELECT friends FROM users WHERE user_id = 'x'
```

And loop the information of users.friends in a second query:

```
SELECT * FROM made WHERE p_id IN ('y', 'z')
```

---

What I basicly need is the information of users.friends (from a specific user.user_id) to find if there's a row exiting in "made" which contains users.friends so I can output the made.result data.

I'm using nodeJS to execute the query such as

```
sql.query("SELECT ....... WHERE user_id = ?", user_id, (err, res) => {......
```

Hopefully I could explain this good enough, it's pretty much complicated to me.

Thanks for the help in future :)

Comment: What is the datatype of column `friends` in table  `users`?

Comment: The datatype of column ```friends``` is ```json```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from what I can infer, you want the union of data from the two tables right?
You can use the inner property.

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

You can see more here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: I guess it's not working with a column that has json data inside. In my case I've got an array with ["123", "456"] and trying to use "IN".

Answer (score 0):

One option is to join using [JSON function `json_search()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) (available starting MySQL 5.7):

```
select m.*
from made m
inner join users u on json_search(u.friends, 'one', m.p_id) is not null
where u.user_id = 'x'
```